# How to find $(f_n)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure $\mu$, but NOT $f_n\rightarrow f$ in almost uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with $\mu (A)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n}$.

How to find $(f_n)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure $\mu$, but NOT $f_n\rightarrow f$ in almost uniformly

Answer (score 1):

Promoting comment to an answer: let $f_n(x)  = 1$ if $x=n$ and $0$ at other $x$.

Almost uniform convergence fails in a strong way: we'd have to remove a set of infinite measure (the tail of harmonic series) to achieve uniform convergence.

By the way, we do have a **subsequence** that converges almost uniformly: $(f_{n^2})$.